# D3JS or Jquery: convert JSON string to integer

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am creating a scatter chart using D3. The input JSON for the chart stores data within quotes, making them strings, while i need it in integer or numeric format.

This is what i am getting,

**var data = [{"collision_with_injury": "2500", "dist_between_fail": "12000"}]**

This is what i need,

**var data = [{collision_with_injury: 2500, dist_between_fail: 12000}]**

Is there a function in D3 or Jquery to convert the data object to one without quotes?

Comment: Adam's comment helped me indirectly. I was not able to add the function as described but prefixing '+' to collision_with_injury and dist_between_fail where i am calling them, resolve it. thanks! '+' converts a string to integer

Comment: Why were you not able to add the function as described in Adam's comment?

Comment: Great! My answer was missing a closing parentheses; I've just edited it in.

Comment: That was it, my bad...i use notepad++ it doesn't give me hints of missing parenthesis. Thanks Adam and Yogesh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.forEach(function(d){
  d.collision_with_injury = +d.collision_with_injury;
  d.dist_between_fail = +d.dist_between_fail;
});
```

If there are more properties in the object that need to be cast as a number, you can iterate over them w/ [d3.keys()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_keys).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXqPt/).

```
var data = [{"collision with injury": "2500", "dist_between_fail": "12AS00"}];
var dataLength = data.length;
if(dataLength>0)
{
    var keys = d3.keys(data[0]);
    var keyLength = keys.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
    {
        var datum = data[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++)
        {
            var key = keys[j];
            if(!isNaN(datum[key])) datum[key]=+datum[key];
        }
    }
}
```